# When should variables be set in a class

Tags: php, oop, constructor

Hay, when should variables be set within a PHP class?

```
<?php
    class MyClass {
        var $my_var;    // here? like var $my_var = null;
        function __construct(){
            $this->my_var = null; // or here?
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what you want to initialise them to. I prefer to initialise them when they're declared if possible, but if they need to be, for example, the result of a method call, then you'll need to initialise them in the constructor.

Comment: So it does not really matter? Either way i want all my variables to be set to null upon creating an instance of the object.

Comment: No it doesn't matter. Just ensure you have them initialized before you intend to use them.

Comment: If you want them set to null then just var $my_var; will do (though you should be using e.g. public $my_var; for PHP5)

Comment: Cheers greg. You've been a big help :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking it would be best to initialize them in the constructor.  I would normally think it's a matter of developer preference, but with the introduction of [auto-implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) with C# 3.0, I think it makes more sense to simply put all intialization in the constructor(s) because you cannot supply a value to a property declared in this manner.  And being consistent about where you intialize variables makes your code more readable.

Comment: Well that's certainly funny... figured it was .NET.  I see everything as pseudo code these days I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the usage of the variable. OOP emphasizes that you initialize your variables in the constructor of the class.

Answer (score 0):

i'd say

```
    class Foo 
    {
        public $bar = 'default';

        function __construct($custom_bar = null) {
            if(!is_null($custom_bar))
                $this->bar = $custom_bar;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you have enough info to set them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To me, a variable initialized at its declaration (outside of the constructor) looks too much like a constant.  It's totally preference, but I choose to initialize in the constructor if at all possible.